# How to make multiple page out of one post

Tags: pagination, content

Suppose I write a long article and display products in one post but it is too long so I want to cut it and continue the next page in the same post? Can I do that in wordpress? I want to display many products so I want to build pages with in a post. One post but there is a navigation numbers like 1 2 3 -- like 3 page in one Post?  How do I do that?

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to take one long post and have it paginated to multiple pages?

Comment: Yes very long post and want to cut it and numbered it but all in one Post, not in another post. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use the WordPress"nextpage" tag:

```
<!--nextpage-->
```

You just drop this into the HTML of your WordPress page wherever you want to break it up.

I think your theme must support this tag in order to handle the pagination - on my site I have page "previous/next" links hidden, but most themes probably support this out of the box.